# What is the preferred Zend Framework 2 (ZF2) way to communicate back end job status to front end?

Tags: doctrine-orm, websocket, zend-framework2, comet

Jobs are implemented using SlmQueueDoctrine. I am considering web sockets or comet however I am uncertain if there is a ZF2 approach or what ZF2 module I should be using?

Answer (score 0):

There is  component/module [ZendQueue](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendQueue)  but it's unkempt. Last status was on Aug 23, 2012 so there is [no stable version](https://github.com/zendframework/ZendQueue/releases) for this package ...

I recommend you to search on packagist.org for better solutions. There are a lot packages for SlmQueue. eg. https://packagist.org/packages/slm/queue

Answer (score 0):

In retrospect, I found that it was more flexible to create a custom queue implementation that persists and communicates jobs through a Doctrine entities (stored in MySQL database). The final custom queue implementation uses [PHP Process Control extensions](http://php.net/manual/en/refs.fileprocess.process.php). It was easier to implement a queue strategy for our use cases.